# How am I able to query master tables/view without pass database name?

Tags: sql-server

Just for curiosity, I'd like to know how I am able to select some system table/view stored in master database without pass the `DB NAME` prefix.

ie, this works fine for [master_files](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-master-files-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) table from any database:

```
use pombo;
go
select * from sys.master_files
```

I have created a table in master database and I need to pass the db_name (master), otherwise it does not work from other database.

ie:

```
select * from dbo.some_table;

Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid object name 'some_table'.
```

Is this configurable? I mean, can I configure a table to be selected from any database without pass the DB NAME? or this behavior only apply to those system tables like [master_files](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-master-files-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)?

Answer (score 3):

While there's no way to create a "global" table (without creating synonyms in each database), there is with stored procedures.

When you create a procedure with the `sp_` prefix in Master it's callable in the context of any database. But the static SQL in the procedure resolves object names in the context of Master database, rather than the context of the database containing the stored procedure. So you can use a procedure called `sp_some_table` to return data in `master.dbo.some_table` from any database.

If you want to reference objects in the local database use dynamic SQL in the stored procedure, as object names in dynamic SQL resolve relative to the current database and the current user's default schema.

Answer (score 2):

> Is this configurable? I mean, can I configure a table to be selected from any database without pass the DB NAME?

No, you have to specify the database context one way or another, either with:

1. The 3-part naming convention (e.g. `SELECT * FROM master.dbo.some_table`)
2. The `USE` keyword to set the context to that database (e.g. `USE master; SELECT * FROM dbo.some_table;`)
3. Specifying the database name `master` as part of your connection string in whichever app you use to connect to the database, so the default context is `master`. (SSMS has a `Default Database` setting you configure for each `Login` object.)

> or this behavior only apply to those system tables like master_files?

`sys.master_files` is a special system-wide view (as mentioned in the docs), which is why it's accessible in any database. When you call it from the `pombo` database, you're using the instance of that view that lives in the `pombo` database. I'm not positive how Microsoft architects it, but I'd assume it's a view in the `model` database, as objects that live in `model` get copied to new user created databases.

> I have created a table in master database

Don't do this. It's not recommended to change the system databases. Whatever you goal is, there's probably a better alternative solution.

Answer (score 2):

Whether you can do this or not depends on:

1. If the view should access a table in the master database or if it is
   expected to access a table in the current database.
2. If you are OK
   with using unsupported functionality.

If the answer to 2 is "no", then you are out of luck, as J.D. and David has written.

If the answer to 2 is "yes" and answer to 1 is that you want to access object in the current database, then again you are out of luck.

If the answer to 2 is "yes" and answer to 1 is that you want to access a table in the master database, then read on:

A lesser known feature in MSSQL is that you can in the master database create a *view* named sp_something. This will make it global, but it will access the table in the *master* database, as shown below:

```
USE master
GO

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS myTable
GO

CREATE TABLE myTable(c1 int)
INSERT INTO myTable(c1) VALUES(42)
GO
CREATE OR ALTER VIEW sp_myView
AS
SELECT c1 FROM myTable
GO

CREATE OR ALTER VIEW sp_myview3
AS
SELECT name from sys.tables WHERE name like 'Sales%'
GO

--Below doesn't change behavior
--EXEC sp_MS_marksystemobject 'sp_myview3'
GO


USE Adventureworks
GO

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS myTable
GO
CREATE TABLE myTable(c1 int)
INSERT INTO myTable(c1) VALUES(99)
GO
--CREATE OR ALTER VIEW sp_myView
--AS
--SELECT c1 FROM myTable
--GO

--CREATE OR ALTER VIEW sp_myview3
--AS
--SELECT name from sys.tables WHERE name like 'Sales%'
--GO


--Returns 42
SELECT * FROM sp_myView

--Doesn't return any of the "sales" tables
SELECT * FROM sp_myView2
```